# Get post terms for multiple posts at once?

Tags: terms

I know I can get the terms for a single post using `wp_get_post_terms`, but is there a way (without writing a loop) to get all the terms in use by an array of posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/). You'd need an array of post id's as the input, together with the taxonomy you want to retrieve the terms for (let's say: books). This should work (untested):

```
$my_query    = new wp_query ($args);
$my_posts    = $my_query->posts;
$my_post_ids = wp_list_pluck ($my_posts, 'ID');
$my_terms    = wp_get_object_terms ($my_post_ids, 'books');
```

Comment: I can confirm this works

Comment: You can return only IDs in your query so that you don't need to use `wp_list_pluck()`

```php
$taxonomy = '{my-taxonomy}';

$args = array(
 'fields'    => 'ids'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$posts = $query->posts;

$terms   = wp_get_object_terms( $posts, $taxonomy );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter